# boost::multi_index insertion function for "other" indices

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

Here is a container of ints with a hashed index and a sequence index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::multi_index_container<
    int,
    boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
        boost::multi_index::hashed_unique<boost::multi_index::identity<int>>,
        boost::multi_index::sequenced<>
        >
    > c;
    for (int i=99; i>=0; --i) c.get<0>().insert(i);
    for (int j : c.get<0>()) std::cout << " " << j;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int k : c.get<1>()) std::cout << " " << k;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 2 1 0   
 99 98 97 96 95 94 93 92 91 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82 81 80 79 78 77 76 75 74 73 72 71 70 69 68 67 66 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 57 56 55 54 53 52 51 50 49 48 47 46 45 44 43 42 41 40 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

The first line shows the elements are "scattered" via the hash index, as expected.  The second line shows the elements are in insertion order via the sequenced index.  But the elements were inserted via the hash index; what can we expect for the elements of the sequenced index?  That is, when `insert` is called for one index, are the insertion functions used for "other" indices defined?

Specifically: When a multi-index container has a hashed index and a sequenced index, and elements are only inserted via the hashed index, will the elements always be in insertion order via the ordered index?

Comment: That's the definition of the "sequenced" index_by key. Internally boost maintains multiple maps from the key space in it's natural order to the list. It's easier to visualize if you think of a multi_index_containers of complex dataset with index_by keys for different fields in the set. When imagined this way, each field has its own sorted mapping that allows fast lookups based on that key. 
When using sequenced keys instead of using one of the fields, you just use the order in which it was inserted. Iteration is guaranteed in the order of the key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for sequenced indices, [docs say](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/seq_indices.html#seq_indices):

*Elements in a sequenced index are by default sorted according to their order of insertion: this means that new elements inserted through a different index of the `multi_index_container` are appended to the end of the sequenced index.*